# Resizing a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to customise the size of my JMenuItems to make them larger. From this:

[image]

to more like this:

[image]

From the looks of things I've got a few options:

1: To extend JMenuItem and override getPreferredSize(). Or I guess do this (which is how the above images were achieved):

```
    private JMenuItem getCustomMenuItem(String s){
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(s){
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(100, 20);
        }
    };
    return item;
}
```

`JMenuItem print = getCustomMenuItem("Print");`

But I'm pretty sure that this is frowned upon because the Layout manager might not respect the size I've given. I might also have to write or override other items, like JCheckBoxMenuItems.

2: I could also add horizontal struts between each of the menu items to deal with vertical spacing, and use spaces on each side of the label to deal with the width of the menu. But this seems clunky, and likely to cause problems when I want to align text and images
`menu.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10))`

3: Or I could add a compound border to each menuItem:
`menuItem.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(menuItem.getBorder(), new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)))`

4: Or somehow tell the look and feel to set Menu item widths - which I don't really understand.

Are there any other ways of doing this? Method 1 works, but I think adding a compound border is probably the way I should go. I suppose I could extend JMenuItem and add the border to the custom item (which would allow me to cast a JCheckBoxMenuItem too)?

Any help is appreciated, haven't really been able to find a definitive answer on this and would like to know what the best practice is for customising components more generally whilst avoiding the whole get/set preferredSize() pitfalls.

Comment: *"I'm currently trying to customise the size of my JMenuItems to make them larger."* ... why?

Comment: the picture above is a bit extreme (i just typed 100 width to test if it would work), but I do think that the default size looks cramped. I just want to be able to alter the visuals slightly

Comment: is it not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

I usually call [setIconTextGap (int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIconTextGap(int)) method to give menu items a better look.

Example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
public class TestMenuItem
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        Locale.setDefault (Locale.ENGLISH);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel (UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName ());
                    createAndShowGUI ();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test Menu Item");
        // --- JMenuBar ---
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar ();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu ("File");
        menu.add (createMenuItem ("Print", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke (KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK)));
        menu.add (createMenuItem ("Exit", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke (KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0)));
        JMenu anotherMenu = new JMenu ("View");
        JMenuItem longerMenuItem = createMenuItem ("Longer Item", null);
        longerMenuItem.setIconTextGap (80);
        anotherMenu.add (longerMenuItem);
        menuBar.add (menu);
        menuBar.add (anotherMenu);
        // --- Closing frame ---
        frame.setJMenuBar (menuBar);
        // frame.pack (); use pack in a real application !!
        frame.setSize (500, 400); // used just for convenience !!
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
    public static JMenuItem createMenuItem (String text, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem (text);
        if (keyStroke != null) menuItem.setAccelerator (keyStroke);
        menuItem.setIconTextGap (40);
        return menuItem;
    }
}
```

This is the result (value = 20):

[image: JMenuItem gap test (value = 20)]

And with larger gap (value = 80):

[image]

Comment: ill have to have a play around with that and see how it looks, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`JMenuItem` extends from `AbstractButton` which has a `setMargin(...)` method:

```
menuItem.setMargin( new Insets(...) );
```

Edit:

Some LAF's allow you to set this property:

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.margin", new Insets(...));
```

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more information.

Comment: oh yeah, I tried this option but it didn't seem to have any effect. I'll try it again now

Comment: yeah, it still doesn't seem to respect that method. I'm calling it right after `JMenuItem print = new JMenuItem("print")`

Comment: @NickW, I've used the setMargin(...) method on a JButton before, not sure why it doesn't work on a menu item. I guess the LAF overrides the functionality. See edit.

Comment: i've actually ended up on your website before - have found some very helpful stuff there, usually things that are poorly described elsewhere, so it's nice to see you've got a post on the UIManager. thanks for the help

Comment: strange - i can definitely set the MenuItem.margin property - I Sysout the property and it shows the correct insets, but it has no impact. I've set the property before any swing component is created, so i'm not sure why it's having no effect. i've also called `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame)` because I read that might help. but it hasn't....

Comment: changing the Font property works fine though. *edit: tried an InsetsUIResource (as that's what the UIManager returned), but no luck there either

Answer (score 0):

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("FILE");
item.add(new JButton("FILE BUTTON"));
item.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // set FlowLayout for item
item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));//set size here
menu.add(item);
```

Comment: i had read that it was better to override getPreferredSize() rather than setting the size. I have no idea why though. 

There's a big thread on preferredSize() on here which I've read a few times, but I'll admit to not really understanding much of it.